# Dynamically changing sheet titles

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2003, vba

I have a several .xls files that have their sheet names the same as their filenames.  Since the sheet names are updated with each .xls file, the code I currently have does not update dynamically.

Is there a way to update the sheet name dynamically so the code can be used across all of the .xls files?

```
Range("A3:E4500").Select
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("named").Range("A3:E4500"), _
PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

where "named" will be dynamically changing. I tried adding this to the code but if gives error messages.  WBname gives the correct name for each sheet but the "Source" does not like the string.

```
Dim WBname As String
WBname = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xls", "")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("A3:E4500").Select
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("WBname").Range("A3:E4500"), _
PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WBname` is a variable. Inside Double Quotes it becomes a string.

Try this

Change

`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("WBname").Range("A3:E4500"), _
PlotBy:=xlColumns`

to this.

`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets(WBname).Range("A3:E4500"), _
PlotBy:=xlColumns`

Comment: WOW i cant believe it was that simple of a change. Thanks, it finally works like i want.